# Keydown and keyup eventlisteners are working properly

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, keycode

I have a code to where I want to detect when someone is pressing a key, then when they release it, the code deletes the code saying they were pressing the key. I tried to piece together some code using information I found online.
Here's what I have so far:

```
 var down = {};
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
        down[evt.keyCode] = true;
        console.log(down)
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        delete down[evt.keyCode];
    });
var p = 0
if (down(65) == 65 && p - 1 >= 0) {
        p -= 1;
    }
    if (down(65) == 68 && p + 1 <= 9) { 
        p += 1;
    }
```

The console keeps saying that down is not a function. How am I to read what keycode they're pressing, but also then delete that instance of keycode after they lift the key.

Comment: Well `down` is *not* a function; you initialized it to `{}`. `down(65)` attempts to call it as a function, and that won't work. You want `down[65]`.

Comment: So how would I read it's value then?

Comment: Replace `down(65) == 65` with `down[65]`

Comment: It needs to be `down["65"]`

Comment: What is the point of storing the key codes in the first place if all you are going to do is delete it as soon as the key is released? Why can't you just log the key that was pressed and forget about `down` entirely? And, when would `down(65) == 65` (even if that syntax worked) ever be `true` if all you ever set `down` keys to is `true` and not the key code?

Comment: Because I'm trying to make it so you can press the key it runs code and then when you release the key it stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the value of your `down` correctly. With objects, bracket or dot notation is the way to go:

```js
var down = {};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  down[evt.keyCode] = true;
  console.log(down)
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
  delete down[evt.keyCode];
});

var p = 0;

if (down[65] === 65 && p - 1 >= 0) {
  p -= 1;
}
if (down[65] == 68 && p + 1 <= 9) {
  p += 1;
}
```

Comment: isnt the first line useless ?

Comment: Are you referring to `var down = {};`?

Comment: Sure it is. Check the event listeners and two conditionals. They all reference it.

Answer (score 1):

It's `down['65']`, not `down(65)`.

You should also test if `down['65']` exists before comparison :

```
if (down['65'] && down['65'] == 65 && p - 1 >= 0) {
    p -= 1;
}
if (down['65'] && down['65'] == 68 && p + 1 <= 9) { 
    p += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change down(65) to down[65] to get it's value.

`down(65)` calling down as function

`down[65]` accessing value of index 65 of a array called down'

Comment: But, the OP has declared `down` as an object, not an array, so there is no index at all. Instead, there are keys and keys are strings, so it has to be `"65"`, not `65`.